# PyQT4 and Ctrl C

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, copy-paste

I have a programs that runs several threads (on a while loop until 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>  is pressed). The app also has a **GUI** that I developed in PyQt. However, I am facing the following problem:

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> on the console, and then close the GUI, the program exits fine. However, if I close the GUI first, the other threads won't stop and the program keeps running after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>. Anyone knows how I could address this problem?

Comment: If you close the GUI, why is the program still running, Ctrl-anything notwithstanding?  Normal behavior for a Qt GUI-based program is to terminate when all the windows close.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt you would overload the OnClose method for the widget/frame or hook the lastwindowsdclosed signal to do whatever you need to shut down the app - don't know if it's diiferent from python